# Trying to click the element found, but it's say that isn't clickable at the point

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm building a bot to get the % of a player in tennis (sofascore.com)

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver2, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/div[@class='cell__content event-team ']")))
link_para_partida = driver2.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/div[@class='cell__content event-team ']")[aux]
link_para_partida.click()
```

It finds the element, but when I try to click, I get this error message:

> the element it's not clickable at the point

and it gave me another element, but it doesn't work

Comment: In your above code, you are collecting elements (more than one). So to click that you have to write for loop which will go to every element and perform click Option. Same has been suggested in the below answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are after this. Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() to get all the players

To click on it induce `javascript` executor to click.

```
driver.get("https://www.sofascore.com/tennis")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='cell__content event-team ']")))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele)
    #Do something
```